# PCA, Better performances with 300 components rather than 400 components : why?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, dimensionality-reduction

I am building this content based image retrieval system. 
I basically extract feature maps of size 1024x1x1 using any backbone. 
I then proceed to apply PCA on the extracted features in order to reduce dimensions. 
I use either nb_components=300 or nb_components=400. 
I achieved these performances (dim_pca means no pca applied)

[image: mAP score]

Is there any explanation of why k=300 works better then k=400 ?
If I understand, k=400 is suppose to explain more variance then k=300 ?
Is it my mistake or a totally acceptable and understandable result ?

Thank you very much

Comment: It's difficult to really know why but imho it's not particularly surprising. Also it looks like the difference might not be significant.

Comment: Thank you Erwan, As long as it is possible, it means that I probably didn't make a mistake.